# Better option than Process.Kill()

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

Is there a better way than to Kill() a process that archives the same result.  When I Kill() an Excel process, the next time I open any Excel Worksheet, "Document Recovery" sidebar is opened, which I do not want to do.

Comment: you'll have to let Excel gracefully exit and wait for it to exit otherwise Excel will always show the document recovery window.

Comment: Is your code starting Excel in the first place? If so, that may provide a nice way of closing Excel once you're done.

Comment: It opens up inside a Web Browser component and does not allow the user to update the worksheet manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will help with Excel running in a web browser. If you can grab the instance of Excel that's running you can find the workbook you want to close...

```
try
{
    // Grab a reference to an open instance of Excel
    var oExcelApp =
        (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)
        Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

    // Loop around the workbooks to find the one you want to close
    for (int i = 1; i <= oExcelApp.Workbooks.Count; i++)
    {
        if (oExcelApp.Workbooks[i].Name == "requiredname")
            oExcelApp.Workbooks[i].Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

    }

    // Clear up...
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oExcelApp);

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // Something went wrong... 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add a .Net reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. Then take a look at the following code I knocked together:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass _excel;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook _workBook;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
    _excel.Visible = true;

    // Open the workbook
    _workBook = _excel.Workbooks.Open(@"DataSheet.xls",
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

}

private void btn_Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    _workBook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    _excel.Quit();

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_workBook);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_excel);

}
```

Comment: I tried this but the next time I open the same file, it gives out error.

Comment: Btw, `Process.Close` is an alias for `Process.Dispose` - it releases your copy of the process handle rather than shut down a running process.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is Excel, how about actually talking to Excel and asking it to close nicely? You can do this using COM.

Comment: Say I want to close DataSheet.xls nicely.  How do I do it using COM?  Any code example?

Comment: See @ [GenericTypeTea](http://stackoverflow.com/users/44269/generictypetea) 's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157051/better-option-than-process-kill/3157061#3157061).

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to call [Process.CloseMainWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx).